# How to get latitude and longitude without live updates?

Tags: android, android-location

I want to query the current latitude and longitude of the user in Android. Every tutorial online uses a listener and keeps updating the location details as it changes. But for my use case, I just need to query it once when needed and get the current latitude and longitude. I don't need real-time updates. How can I query the current location details without any real-time updates?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do it:

1)Use requestSingleUpate instead of requestLocationUpdates.  Single is a 1 shot request.

2)Use requestLocationUpdates, and unregister in the callback.

You can check getLastKnownLocation to see if there's already a location in the system, but 99% of the time there won't be and you'll have to fall back to 1 or 2.  It can be a speed optimization, but you can't rely on it.